# How to override a function when Parent already explicitly `setattr` the same function?

Tags: python, inheritance, setattr

A 'minimal' example I created:

```
class C:
    def wave(self):
        print("C waves")

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        c = C()
        setattr(self, 'wave', getattr(c, 'wave'))

class B(A):
    def wave(self):
        print("B waves")

>>> a = A()
>>> a.wave()
C waves # as expected
>>> b = B()
>>> b.wave()
C waves # why not 'B waves'?
>>>
```

In the example, class `A` explicitly defined its method `wave` to be class `C`'s `wave` method, although not through the more common function definition, but using `setattr` instead. Then we have class `B` that inherits `A`, `B` tries to override `wave` method with its own method, however, that's not possible, what is going on? how can I work around it?

I want to keep class `A`'s `setattr` style definition if at all possible, please advise.

I've never systematically learned Python so I guess I am missing some understanding regarding how Python's inheritance and `setattr` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class A sets the `wave()` method as its *instance* attribute in `__init__()`. This can be seen by inspecting the instance's dict:

```py
>>> b.__dict__
{'wave': <bound method C.wave of <__main__.C object at 0x7ff0b32c63c8>>}
```

You can get around this by deleting the instance member from `b`

```py
>>> del b.__dict__['wave']
>>> b.wave()
B waves
```

With the instance attribute removed, the `wave()` function is then taken from the class dict:

```py
>>> B.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              'wave': <function __main__.B.wave(self)>,
              '__doc__': None})
```

The thing to note here is that when Python looks up an attribute, instance attributes take precedence over the class attributes (unless a class attribute is a data [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), but this is not the case here).

I have also written a [blog post](https://blog.peterlamut.com/2018/11/04/python-attribute-lookup-explained-in-detail/) back then explaining how the attribute lookup works in even more detail.

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I'm looking for!

Comment: I have also updated my answer with a link to a blog post of mine, in case you want to know even more details about the attribute lookup machinery (would almost be too much to include all the details in the answer itself).